# MySQL "group by" limit groups returned

Tags: php, mysql, sql

If I apply a limit when selecting with group by, the limit is applied to the number of groups returned or the number of rows?

Myself, I want to limit the groups returned.

Here's my trial:

```
select * from orders group by customer_email limit 0,2
```

From this table:

```
id customer_email
0 a@a.com
1 a@a.com
2 a@a.com
3 b@b.com
4 c@c.com
5 c@c.com
6 d@d.com
```

I want returned rows 0,1,2,3,4,5.

Comment: What is the result of above query ?

Comment: it will return the limited groups not rows. You want limit the groups but you need rows returned 0 1 2 3 4 5 ?

Comment: This should give an error as you haven't used any aggregate function though using group by

Comment: Specify that what exactly you want because if you want this output then why are you using group by. So please add some understandable information in your question

Comment: Surely what you need is a where clause if you want to limit the groups rather than the number of results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little ambiguous: the proposed query limits to 2 groups, and you seem to want all the rows with equal `customer_email` that are contained in the first 3 groups.

Anyway, here is my answer for as far as I correctly understand your question :)

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT customer_email
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY customer_email
    LIMIT 0,3
) AS temp
ON orders.customer_email = temp.customer_email
```

The sub query `select customer_email from orders group by customer_email limit 0,3` selects the first 3 groups, then you select all the rows in `order` that contain the same `customer_email` as in the first 3 groups which would give you row 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.